# Start Activity with SearchView open

Tags: android, searchview

how can I start an activity with a SearchView with the text field open.
In this way I could search without having to click on the spyglass.
I am using Sherlock Action Bar.

Here is my code:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        searchView.setQueryHint("Cerca domande");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (query.length() != 0) {

                    // handle search here
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                 if (newText.length()>=3) {
                     new PostTask().execute(newText);   

                     Util.setSharedPreferences(SearchActivity.this, "lastsearch", newText);
                 }
                return false;
            }
        });

        menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(ic_search_inverse)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);


        listsearch.setOnItemClickListener(this);

     return true;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tried this?

```
searchMenu.expandActionView();
```

in `OnCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(ic_search_inverse)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .expandActionView();
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

you can add focus, open soft-keyboard. So, that everything is ready for user to type in and search.

But this isn't the standard behavior.

Comment: I'm looking into your answer @Archie.bpgc and searching about expandActionView(). ANyway, there is no searchMenu object in my code. Thanks

Comment: :| By `searchMenu` I mean the search menu item you added to your menu

Comment: Calling expandActionView() on the searchMenu didn't work for me. But     searchView.setIconified(false) on the ActionView had the text input open by default.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post.

Comment: Looks like a valid suggestion, but you should write it as an answer if you're not really asking a question. Or, if you're seeking clarification, post it as a comment instead.